# Ubuntu 16.04 does not power off

Tags: grub2, shutdown, acer

I recently bought an Acer Aspire ES1-533-C4WF with some custom Linux distro in (no GUI).

I had many failed attempts to intall Ubuntu 16.04 because the installation was every time hanging while installing Grub2.

I found a solution [here (Second post from user Pueseso)](http://community.acer.com/t5/E-F-and-M-Series-Laptops/Acer-Aspire-ES-15-ES1-533-C3UW-Legacy-BIOS-Missing/td-p/471754/page/2) to install without boot loader, and then install grub manually.

Finally managed to get it boot and it everything works fine. Except from... shuting down. The proccess hangs on the ubuntu screen. If a press Esc the last line printed is:

```
[some-number] reboot:Power down
```

[image]

I tried many posible fixes around the net, for example editing the `/etc/default/grub` file (adding or removing various parametest in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` lines) and then `update-grub`.

The only thing I achieved was to sometimes make my touchpad not working (not sure how is this related, but was back to normal if I reverted the changes, update-grub and restart). Problem remained

I also tried kernel 4.9 and 4.10. No luck.
Closing from command line, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, no luck either.

Any help is welcome!
Thanks!

Edit: hibernate also does not work. System sleeps and wakes up straght away.